# MySQL error 2013 timeout

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run a massive query and this happens.

I am using heidisql to execute the

```
load data infile
```

command but with a file of over 1million entries it keeps failing. I have seen elsewhere that this command

```
--net_read_timeout=100
```

is what i should be using but how do u put that in a query as it doesnt work just typing that into the php my admin kind of window. is it an sql mode command??

for some reason stack overflow wont let me post this question yet as it does not meet their standards so im just going to keep typing until it allows me to submit

Comment: What is the complete error message?

Comment: here it is /* SQL Error (2013): Lost connection to MySQL server during query */

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of `max_allowed_packet`

Change in the my.ini/my.cnf file. Include the single line under `[mysqld]` in your file

```
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

now `restart the MySQL service` once you are done. You can see it's curent value in mysql like this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

You can try to change it like this, but it's unlikely this will work on shared hosting:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216;
```

You can read about it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: yeah it wont let me SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216;

Comment: Just add this max_allowed_packet=500M in My.ini/my.cnf ubder [mysqld] section. And DO NOT FORGET TO RESTART THE SERVER.

Comment: but i am on shared hosting with go daddy, how do you access that file and how do you restart the server :/